# Error in MySQL Query (error in your SQL syntax)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute below query in MySQL

```
DELETE FROM zc_products zcp 
WHERE zcp.products_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id FROM zc_products p, zc_products_to_categories pc WHERE 
p.products_id = pc.products_id AND 
pc.categories_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT zcc.categories_id FROM zc_categories zcc WHERE zcc.categories_status = 0))
```

and getting below error:

> Query: Delete from zc_products zcp where zcp.products_id in (SELECT
>   DISTINCT p.products_id as pid FROM zc_products p, zc_products_to_ca...
>
> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'zcp  where zcp.products_id in (SELECT DISTINCT
>   p.products_id as pid FROM zc_prod' at line 1

I am trying everything to fix this but no luck.

Would request others to help me in this please.

Comment: lose the zcp alias

Answer (score 0):

You have an `unexpected identifier` in your `SQL` statement ...  This is because you are using the `alias` **zcp** unnecessarily.  With the `SQL` that you have, there is no need to `alias` the `table` in the `DELETE` clause.

```
DELETE FROM zc_products
WHERE products_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT p.products_id FROM zc_products p, zc_products_to_categories pc WHERE 
p.products_id = pc.products_id AND 
pc.categories_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT zcc.categories_id FROM zc_categories zcc WHERE zcc.categories_status = 0));
```

**NOTE**
If you used a tool like MySQL Workbench -- It would identify the problem *for* you ... Allowing you to troubleshoot more easily.