# Error in Executing SQL DELETE Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to develop a database for "Diseases Detection Management System " on phpmyAdmin using MAMP server. I am also trying to apply SQL queries on this database like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE etc.But during executing DELETE query I got an error.

Delete Statement:

```
DELETE FROM `disease_information` WHERE `Disease_name`=`Fever`
```

But when i simulate the above query it display the following error message:

Error Message:

```
 #1054 - Unknown column 'Fever' in 'where clause'
```

I had searched about this error on many websites and on stack overflow also but don't get the relevent answer.Here is the link from where i had searched.

Link:
[Link of stackoverflow from where i had searched about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567803/error-in-mysql-query-error-in-your-sql-syntax)

Kindly help me to remove the above error so that i will move forward.

Comment: Put fever in quotes and remove quotes from tablename and columnname

Comment: Use single quotes around fever

Comment: You are simply using the wrong kind of quotes. One kind is for identifiers, the other is for text values.

Comment: e_information` WHERE `Disease_name`=`Fever`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use normal quote marks rather than backticks around Fever. Might help

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM `disease_information` WHERE `Disease_name`='Fever'
```